# Using Merge instead of SaveOrUpdate

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have the code below. It sometimes gives the runtime error:

> a different object with the same identifier value was already
>   associated with the session

I saw a solution which suggests using `Merge` instead of `SaveOrUpdate`. When trying that (see commented out line). I get a compile error:

> The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter
>   `T` in the generic type or method

The solution to this error says to add `T : class` to the class declaration. It already has `T : new()`. When I change it to "class" I get other compile errors.

> 'T' must be an abstract type with a public parameterless constructor
>   in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

and also see `GetDefaultInstance()`

How do I do this?

```
public class GenericNHibernateDataService<T, ID> : Interface.Data.IGenericDataService<T, ID> where T : new() 
    public virtual T GetDefaultInstance()
    {
        return new T(); // compile error when changing to T : class
        // Cannot create an instance of the variable type 'T' because it does not have the new constraint
    }

    public virtual T SaveOrUpdate (T entity)
    {
        NHibernate.ITransaction tx = null;

        try
        {
            tx = this.Session.BeginTransaction();
            this.Session.SaveOrUpdate (entity);
            //Session.Merge(entity); //The type T must be a reference type in order to use it as a parameter `T` in the generic type or method

            tx.Commit();
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            tx.Rollback();
            throw ex;
        }
        return entity;
    }
    ...
```

}

Comment: Have you tried adding both constraints: `where T : class, new()`?

Comment: That works! Post that as the answer if you like.

Comment: Done. Glad that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add both constraints:

```
where T : class, new()
```